# Virtualenv doesn't install pip

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, virtualenv, pip

I have installed `python3` via homebrew, updated `pip` & `setuptools`, installed `virtualenv` via `pip`. Now I'm trying to create a virtual env. Unfortunately, I can't get it to add pip to the virtualenv. Basically:

```
$ ls -lha venv/bin/
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  9 foghin  staff   306B Jan 19 17:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 foghin  staff   204B Jan 19 17:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 foghin  staff   2.2K Jan 19 17:16 activate
-rw-r--r--  1 foghin  staff   1.2K Jan 19 17:16 activate.csh
-rw-r--r--  1 foghin  staff   2.4K Jan 19 17:16 activate.fish
-rw-r--r--  1 foghin  staff   1.1K Jan 19 17:16 activate_this.py
lrwxr-xr-x  1 foghin  staff     7B Jan 19 17:16 python -> python3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 foghin  staff    13K Jan 19 17:16 python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 foghin  staff     7B Jan 19 17:16 python3.3 -> python3
```

AFAIK `pip` is supposed to be there as well. Creating the virtual env with high verbosity yields this:

```
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Running command /Users/foghin/code/tastekid/venv/bin/python3 -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip
  Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages
  Cleaning up...
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

This means that all the packages I install while the virtual env is activated go to my global site packages (`/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages`), but they are not picked up by the sandboxed python.

How can I get `virtualenv` to properly install pip in my local environment?

**Update:** virtualenv version is 1.11.

Comment: Try creating the environment with `virtualenv --no-site-packages`.

Comment: You should mention the exact version number of `virtualenv`, so that if this is a bug, it will be easier to track it down.

Comment: @minitech from `virtualenv --help`: `--no-site-packages    DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward compatibility. Not having access to global site-packages is now the default behavior.`

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo updated my question to include `virtualenv` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, Homebrew installs Python 3.3.3 (`$ brew info python3`).

And as of Python 3.3, Python's standard library now includes its own virtual environment implementation, and does not require the virtualenv package. See the [`venv` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). With the Homebrew Python 3 package, the command-line tool is named `pyvenv-3.3`.

I believe using this implementation should resolve the issues you're encountering.

Comment: I've tried `pyvenv` as well, but that explicitly doesn't install `pip` and `setuptools`. I ended up installing them manually in the virtual environment, which seems to have worked. However, this still doesn't answer why `virtualenv` doesn't work as advertised.